# Python Emailing with encoded deisgned ( html ) text

Tags: python, html, email, encode

I have a working send email script which takes txt file and send it encoded.

- i want to be able to design (html) this encoded txt in the email body.
- i know how generally design a text in email body but i cant design the encoded txt in the html.

i want to combine the two scripts and be able to design the encoded text ( first script output) into the html design of the second script

first script  send email ( Works but undesigned body ):

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# mailing cofig:


ID = 'XX
PASSWORD = XX
email_reciever = XX
filename = r".\Reports\Report.txt"


def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(ID, PASSWORD)
        message = 'Subject:{}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(ID, email_reciever, message)
        # server.sendmail(ID, email_reciever, msg.as_string())

        print('Succes')
    except Exception as e:
        # Print any error messages to stdout
        print(e)
    finally:
        server.quit()


msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Your BeeHero Report'
msg['From'] = ID
msg['To'] = email_reciever

with open(filename, "r") as filename:
    text = ''.join(filename.readlines()[1:])

msg.set_payload(text.encode())

subject = "BeeHero Report"

send_email(subject, msg)
```

output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EON2h.jpg

Second script ( designed body but not encoded as the first output)

```
# Sending email script Amit
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# mailing cofig:


ID = XX
PASSWORD = XX
email_reciever = XX
filename = r".\Reports\Report.txt"


def send_email(msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(ID, PASSWORD)
        server.sendmail(ID, email_reciever, msg.as_string())

        print('Succes')
    except Exception as e:
        # Print any error messages to stdout
        print(e)
    finally:
        server.quit()


msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Your BeeHero Report'
msg['From'] = ID
msg['To'] = email_reciever

with open(filename, "r") as filename:
    text = ''.join(filename.readlines()[1:])



html = (f"""
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <body>
         <h1 style="color:SlateGray;">{text}</h1>
     </body>
 </html>
 """)


part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')


msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)



send_email(msg)
```

output:

https://imgur.com/a/5wqUoSa